Cannot render revealjs files - Parameterized reporting in R using Quarto
I attempted to render a revealjs presentation using parameterized reporting. Even though I specified revealjs as the format in the YAML header and set the output_format to "revealjs" in the quarto_render function, I still ended up with a standard HTML file without revealjs functionality.
When I render the revealjs.qmd file (Individual_Report.qmd) directly, it works fine. The issue only occurs when I use the parameterized reporting R script.
Here is the YAML header:
---
title: "ABC"
format
  revealjs:
theme: default
embed-resources: true
params:
  token: null
---

Here is the R script
library(quarto)
library(tidyverse)
library(haven)
library(here)

setwd("S:/Projects/Benchmarking/Individual Reports Output")

data <- read_dta('S:/Projects/Benchmarking/Data/data_respondents_benchmarking.dta')

data <- data %>%
  mutate(across(c(function_group, function_subgroup, token), as_factor)) %>%
  mutate(across(-c(function_group, function_subgroup, token), as.numeric))

set.seed(123)  
subset_data <- data %>%
  slice_sample(n = 2)


tokens <- 
  subset_data |>
  distinct(token) |>
  pull(token) |>
  as.character()

reports <-
  tibble(
    output_file = file.path(str_glue("{tokens}.html")),
    execute_params = map(tokens, ~list(token = .))
  )


pwalk(reports,
      quarto_render,
      input = here::here("S:/Projects/Benchmarking/Individual_Report.qmd"),
      output_format = "revealjs",
      .progress = TRUE
      )

Does anyone see what the issue could be?

Could this be just a typo in the YAML-header (hierarchy, missing colons ...)? See position of embed-resources in documentation.

Thank you for the answer. The error was because the output files were being saved to setwd("S:/Projects/Benchmarking/Individual Reports Output") while the Individual_Report.qmd" was stored in "S:/Projects/Benchmarking".
Due to this all the plugins stored in Individual_Report_files/libs were not being accessed.
Changing the working directory to setwd("S:/Projects/Benchmarking") solved the issue!

Thank you for the answer. The error was because the output files were being saved to setwd("S:/Projects/Benchmarking/Individual Reports Output") while the Individual_Report.qmd" was stored in "S:/Projects/Benchmarking".
Due to this all the plugins stored in Individual_Report_files/libs were not being accessed.
Changing the working directory to setwd("S:/Projects/Benchmarking") solved the issue!

Remember to mark your answer as "accepted" so that the question is filed under solved.
